# How do I move the cursor to the front of a textbox which has text in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this text box:

```
<input type="text" name="url" id="url-input" />
```

and this code:

```
var inputText = "Hello World";
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#url-input").focus();
  $("#url-input").val(inputText);
});
```

As it is, the cursor is displayed at the end of the textbox after the words "Hello World" (no matter in which order I add focus or change the value).  How can I move it to the front?

Thanks

**EDIT** - Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dmRND/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In decent web browsers, you have access to the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties which represent the selection. When they are both `0`, it comes down to no selection and the caret at the beginning:

```
$("#url-input").prop('selectionStart', 0)
               .prop('selectionEnd', 0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/efek3/

Another thing of jQuery is chaining: `$(...).func1().func2()`, so you need the selector once only.

Yet another thing of jQuery is that most functions support objects as parameter so you could also do:

```
$("#url-input").prop({ selectionStart: 0,
                       selectionEnd:   0 });
```

Comment: @Nick Brunt: That remembers me of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263743/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-textarea/3373056#3373056.

Answer (score 0):

I use this small jquery plug in:
https://gist.github.com/DrPheltRight/1007907